# Rails routes.rb - Matching case insensitive

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Urls are (for an unclear reason, generate different problems/no real advantage) defined case sensitive by w3.

What are my possibilities in routes.rb match case insensitively?

here the matching:

```
match '/:foo/library/:bar' => 'library#show'
```

Url Example: /europe/library/page4711

calls show action in library controller with { :foo => "europe", :bar => "page4711" }

*What I want are 2 things:*

- the param value of :foo needs a .downcase so /Europe should be {
  :foo => "europe" }
- library should match case insensitively (ie. /Library, /LIBRARY,
  /liBRarY all should match)

How do I do this in routes.rb?

Thanks!

Comment: @shioyama: I finally got to make this as a gem: https://rubygems.org/gems/route_downcaser

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, to answer my own question:

There is no good way to do this within Rails routes.rb.

Here what I did:

For the first thing I created a before_filter in my controller:

```
before_filter :foo_to_lower_case

def foo_to_lower_case
  params[:foo] = params[:foo].downcase
end
```

For the second one I created a load balancer rule to get it lowercase to the rails app. Of course you can define a nginx/apache rule as well instead.

**Edit**: I found another solution for the second part because I disliked the pre-parsing/replacing of every url.

I made "library" to a symbol and wrote a constrained for it which only accept any form of the word "library".

So the line in routes.rb looks like:

```
match '/:foo/:library/:bar' => 'library#show', :constraints => { :library => /library/i }
```

Comment: optimization: `params[:foo].downcase!`

Answer (score 3):

Just add this to your Gemfile

```
gem 'route_downcaser'
```

restart rails, no configuration needed.
the github for this project is at:

https://github.com/carstengehling/route_downcaser

As noted in the gem "Querystring parameters and asset paths are not changed in any way."

Comment: nice, but would be nice to be more specific

Comment: Careful, this gem is way too easy to use.

Answer (score 2):

To downcase the path, you could set up an initializer to add a Rack middleware. Here I'm checking whether the path begins with `/posts` and `posts` isn't part of a longer word. See the code comments for more info.

```
class PathModifier
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    if env['PATH_INFO'] =~ /^\/posts\b/i
      Rails.logger.debug("modifying path")
      %w(PATH_INFO REQUEST_URI REQUEST_PATH ORIGINAL_FULLPATH).each do |header_name|
        # This naively downcases the entire String. You may want to split it and downcase
        # selectively. REQUEST_URI has the full url, so be careful with modifying it.
        env[header_name].downcase!
      end
    end
    @app.call(env)
  end
end
Rails.configuration.middleware.insert(0, PathModifier)
```